# How to pass array of Objects to table

Tags: reactjs

I am getting some confusion in sending data . Bellow given is response from rest. I want to send this given data in table.

```
data = [ 
  {name :'user 1' , teams : [ {id: 1, name : team 1}, {id :2, name :'team 2'}..]}
{name : 'user 2',teams :[ {id: 2, name: team 2},{id: 4, name: team 4} ..] 
]
```

Expected result

Username           Teams

user 1             team 1 team 2
user 2             team 2 team 4

Teams has to be Clickable , while passing team names, want to pass team id also as id. while clicking on  table some particular event has to be occurred so i show able to click.
Please help to implement this.
Thanks

Comment: Too broad. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am getting confused on how to implement. Please suggest what i can do.

Comment: create an object bind the json data with the object and then bind that on your html table. Do you want to use any row span for such table structure or what? Please be more specific about your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused with the table structure below is a possible way to bind such array into table. Assuming that you have set the state with data once the rest returns the array. Following is the snippets of react render method where you will bind the table html. Hope this helps.

```
<table className="table table-responsive table-striped center-align" >
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col" >Team</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {this.state.data.map((dataItem) => {
            let count = 0;
            dataItem['teams '].map((item) => {
                <tr>
                    {++count == 1 ?
                        <td rowSpan={dataItem['teams'].length}>{dataItem.name}</td>
                        : null
                    }
                    <td>
                        {item.name}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            })
        })
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```